# Open problems in the theory of manifolds relating to construction

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, sg.symplectic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, open-problems

A while ago I stumbled across a paper of Thurston: Some Simple Examples of Symplectic Manifolds, where Thurston constructs closed symplectic manifolds with no Kaehler structure. My question is: What are the most rewarding and beautiful (potential) manifolds that one might seek to construct, that have not been constructed thus far? (Does there exist [insert]?). Obviously potential constructions are not restricted to manifolds , however I am mostly interested in constructions of manifolds or spaces in the most current and/or new areas of research in geometry and topology. I would also be interested in conjectures (interconnected or otherwise) relating to manifolds that can be resolved via constructions, what constructions?

Comment: Why the functional analysis and k-theory tags?

Comment: This is way too broad and vague.  I've voted to close.